# Can't remove whitespaces from textarea

Tags: php, textarea, removing-whitespace

I have two files. First file is a form and the second file displays result.

First file:

```
<form action="show.php" method=post>
<textarea name="test" cols=40 rows=6>
</textarea>
<input type=submit value="submit">
</form>
```

Second file:

```
<?php
$text = trim($_POST['test']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($textAr); $i++)
{
    $link = str_replace(" ", "", $textAr[$i]);
    echo $link."---<br>";
}
?>
```

When I enter in the form for example

```
one
two
three
```

the result is:

```
one ---
two ---
three---
```

at the end on the strings: one and two there are whitespaces that I can't remove. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks I used $link = str_replace("\r", "", $textAr[$i]) and now everything is ok

Comment: probably due to the carriage return in the textarea. try stripping out \n and \r from the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim()` instead of `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function instead of using `str_replace` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `textarea`'s linebreaks are `\r\n` in Internet Explorer, and `\n` in all other browsers (including Mac's). IE uses `\n` too since version 9.

There are numerous ways to fix your code. For example, you could try [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) :

```
preg_split('/(?:\r\n|\n)/', $text);
```

However, I haven't tested the performances of this proposal.

Also, very important, be sure to put the `\r\n` before the `\n` in the regex!

Besides, [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is way more suited than [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (of course if you still need it).

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but may help others.

use this in when document indentation is required.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('textarea').each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's non space whitespaces like non-break-spaces (nbsp) or some part of a linebreak combination?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function, could be carriage return or new line (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

Comment: Thanks I used $link = str_replace("\r", "", $textAr[$i]) and now everything is ok.