# Getting lots of white space characters

Tags: php, html

i'm currently creating a piece of code which should simply show the text that is stored in the url via php in a variable QuoteText, like so:

```
post.php?PostID=7&QuoteText=This is a post
```

I have created the code to make a text area get this text and it should display in the text box. However for some reason I keep getting alot of whitespace characters in the text area box, although there is none in text being gotten.

```
Start of box |        This is a post                   | end of box
```

Can anybody help explain why i keep getting this problem? Thanks, i've added the code for the textarea below

```
<textarea name="commentMade" rows="" cols="" class="COMMENTBOX" required=required>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['QuoteText']) != "") 
    echo $_GET['QuoteText'];
else 
    echo "COMMENTS HERE :)";
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Not the problem, but... `isset($_GET['QuoteText']) != ""` doesn't make much sense. `if boolean value != ''`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the extra whitespace is coming from your PHP inside `<textarea></textarea>` tags. What you can do is this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['QuoteText']) != "")
    $txt = $_GET['QuoteText'];
else 
    $txt = "COMMENTS HERE :)";
?>
<textarea name="commentMade" rows="" cols="" class="COMMENTBOX" required=required><?php echo(trim($txt)); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Aleks G could be correct as spaces could be around outside the php tags.

Comment: @bardiir: you're right, I didn't express myself clear.  As dev pointed out, there could be spaces around outside the `php` tags - plus the newlines before and after the the php block itself.

Comment: Yep, it's probably whitespaces before and after the php tags, everything inbetween is pretty much irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
if(isset($_GET['QuoteText']) != "") 
    echo trim($_GET['QuoteText']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace is probably in your php file at the end of the lines. Be aware that inside of `<textarea>` like in `<pre`> you can't freely set whitespaces like in other places of your html syntax, they will be displayed there.

Take a look at your HTML source that you generate and make sure there are no rogue whitespaces.

This might be related:
[Why is textarea filled with mysterious white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202999/why-is-textarea-filled-with-mysterious-white-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your code to `... required><?php ...`.

But regardless of the reasons, a `trim()` should let you get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Make that single line, spaces could be there at start or rear of lines.

```
<textarea name="commentMade" rows="" cols="" class="COMMENTBOX" required=required><?php 
echo (isset($_GET['QuoteText']))? $_GET['QuoteText'] : "COMMENTS HERE :)";
?></textarea>
```