# JavaScript textarea character counter inserting tab

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

When users on my site go to set their bio for their profile, there is a Javascript character counter to show how many characters they have remaining.

When they go to write a new bio or edit their current one, inside the  tags their current bio is echo'd in PHP from the database. Here's the code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 300;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');
    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
      var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
      var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
       $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
  });
</script>
<form action="profile_edit_bio.php" method="post">
  <textarea id="textarea" name="bio" class="input-xxlarge" maxlength="300" placeholder="Update your bio! This should be a short paragraph explaining why you're awesome. (Max characters 300)">
    <?php if(strlen($row[20])!=0) {echo $row[20];}?>
  </textarea>
  <div id="textarea_feedback">
    If you're seeing this message, please <a href="mailto:support@jaycraft.co">contact support</a>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update bio</button>
</form>
```

When they hit the submit button in the form, it saves the bio successfully and everything, but now it shows their bio with the `<?php if(strlen($row[20])!=0) {echo $row[20];}?>` with loads of tabs around it.

So, for example

> Hello, my name is James

Would become

> ```
>                           Hello, my name is James
> ```

It's definitely something wrong with the script, because it doesn't save these spaces/tabs to the database.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202999/why-is-textarea-filled-with-mysterious-white-spaces

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that, mod please merge this with that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inserting the tabs yourself. **ANYTHING** between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` becomes part of the displayed editable text. Your code should be

```
<textarea>$text_to_insert</textarea>
```

Note that lack of any whitespace between the tags and the inserted variable/text.Your version is

```
<textarea>[linebreak]
[tab][tab][tab]$text_to_insert[linebreak]
</textarea>
```