# trim() function not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, trim

I am making an edit form in wordpress. This is my code. My `trim()` function is not working.

```
<div class = "input-group">
    <label for = "business_meta_title"><?php _e('Meta Title', 'wcd');
?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_title" id="business_meta_title" class="form-control">
        <?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_title', $deal_id)); ?>
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="business_meta_description"><?php _e('Meta Description', 'wcd'); ?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_description" id="business_meta_description" class="form-control">
        <?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_description', $deal_id)); ?>
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="business_meta_keywords"><?php _e('Meta Keywords', 'wcd'); ?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_keywords" id="business_meta_keywords" class="form-control">
        <?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_keywords', $deal_id)); ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I am getting output like this.

[image]

Any thoughts? What should I do?

Comment: `trim()` has nothing to do with it. `trim()` just removes leading and trailing whitespaces from the returned text of the php function/variable. What you have is a styling issue, not a php issue

Comment: remove spaces in `textarea`  `<textarea type="text" name="business_meta_keywords" id="business_meta_keywords" class="form-control"><?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_keywords', $deal_id));?></textarea>`  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202999/why-is-textarea-filled-with-mysterious-white-spaces

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please re-write your `textareas` by having no spaces in them, `trim` works fine but you are adding the extra spaces after opening `textarea` tag in your **HTML**:

```
<div class = "input-group">
    <label for = "business_meta_title"><?php _e('Meta Title', 'wcd');
?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_title" id="business_meta_title" class="form-control"><?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_title', $deal_id)); ?></textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="business_meta_description"><?php _e('Meta Description', 'wcd'); ?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_description" id="business_meta_description" class="form-control"><?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_description', $deal_id)); ?></textarea>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="business_meta_keywords"><?php _e('Meta Keywords', 'wcd'); ?></label>
    <textarea type="text" name="business_meta_keywords" id="business_meta_keywords" class="form-control"><?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_keywords', $deal_id)); ?></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked. I am using netbeans. It automatically formatted the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use  without spaces between value in tag as:

```
<textarea type="text" name="business_meta_keywords" id="business_meta_keywords" class="form-control"><?php echo trim(get_field('business_meta_keywords', $deal_id)); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked. I am using netbeans. It automatically formatted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two changes point which may solve your issue:
**1.** If you working with wordpress then please use wordpress provided [wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) instead `trim()`.

**2.** Remove spacing between value and `<textarea>` tag

`wp_trim_words()` function trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text.

Comment: `wp_trim_words()` and `trim()` is completely different. `trim()` removes leading and trailing white spaces from a string, `wp_trim_words()` trim the amount of words in a string, it does not remove white spaces in the beginning and end of a string. Your answer is totally wrong