# Placeholder not visible in Textarea

Tags: html

I am having a slight issue with my textarea in html, when I add the Placeholder attribute it doesn't seem to be visible until I highlight and press backspace also the cursor appears further away from the initial leftmost position.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Post a Task
  </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">



</head>
<body>
<div class="card" style="width: 50rem; margin-top: -40px; padding: 20px; margin: auto;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title text-center"  id="Signup_Title">POST YOUR TASK </h5>
      <!--<h6 class="card-title text-center"  id="Signup_Sub_Title"></h6>-->
      <form>

        <div id="formpage_1">
          
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label>Brief Title:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" rows="2"  placeholder="Brief Title">
                    
                  </textarea>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>Detailed Description:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" rows="8"  placeholder="Detailed Description">
                
              </textarea>
              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="menu" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
                style="background-color:#f9d342 ; color:#252218 ; border: none; width: 30%;">Attach File
                </button>
            </div>

     
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your placeholder works fine in Chrome

Comment: Have you tried removing the line break inside the `<textarea>` element? Works fine in Firefox.

Comment: I think its important i mention that i am using bootstrap and am attaching a form-control class to the textarea

Comment: @Wales77 Please provide a [mcve]. We can't help you if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SebastianSimon don't understand

Comment: @Wales77 The line break between `<textarea cols = "30" rows = "8" placeholder = "Detailed Description">` and `</textarea>`. Remove it.

Comment: Provide your css as well

Comment: I just editied my post the actual code is what i have there now@Ramesh

Comment: @Wales77 as Sebastian mentioned, remove the white-space between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`. They should be on the same line with nothing between them. Otherwise anything that is between those open and close tags is considered its value and because it is not empty, it wont show the placeholder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is textarea filled with mysterious white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202999/why-is-textarea-filled-with-mysterious-white-spaces)

Comment: Yeah i just did it and it worked fine

Comment: also you are missing a `</form>` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is textarea filled with mysterious white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202999/why-is-textarea-filled-with-mysterious-white-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Post a Task
  </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">



</head>
<body>
<div class="card" style="width: 50rem; margin-top: -40px; padding: 20px; margin: auto;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title text-center"  id="Signup_Title">POST YOUR TASK </h5>
      <!--<h6 class="card-title text-center"  id="Signup_Sub_Title"></h6>-->
      <form>

        <div id="formpage_1">
          
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label>Brief Title:</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" rows="2"  placeholder="Brief Title"></textarea>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label>Detailed Description:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" rows="8"  placeholder="Detailed Description"></textarea>
              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="menu" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
                style="background-color:#f9d342 ; color:#252218 ; border: none; width: 30%;">Attach File
                </button>
            </div>
```

REMOVED WHITE SPACE